# Atiyah and Macdonald Exercise 1.5(v)

Tags: commutative-algebra

If someone could check my proof for the following question, I would appreciate it!

> Let $A$ be a ring, and let $A[[x]]$ be the formal power series ring. Show that every prime ideal of $A$ is the contraction of a prime ideal in $A[[x]]$.

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $A$. There is the canonical surjective quotient map:
$$ \psi: A\to A/\mathfrak{p} $$
There is an isomorphism between $A[[x]]/(x)$ and $A$ induced by the following map $\phi$ which sends every power series to its constant term with kernel $(x)\subset A[[x]]$:
$$ \phi: A[[x]] \to A $$
Therefore, the surjective map $\psi\circ \phi: A[[x]]\to A/\mathfrak{p}$ has kernel:
$$ \ker(\psi\circ \phi) = (x) + \mathfrak{p}A[[x]] $$
($\supset$ is clear. Suppose $f\in \ker(\psi\circ \phi)$ then $f$ has constant term in $\mathfrak{p}$ and the higher order terms can be anything. Thus, clearly $f\in (x) + \mathfrak{p}A[[x]]$.)

Therefore, $(x)+\mathfrak{p}A[[x]]$ is prime, since $A[[x]]/((x)+\mathfrak{p}A[[x]]) \cong A/\mathfrak{p}$ is an integral domain. Moreover, $((x)+\mathfrak{p}A[[x]])^c = \mathfrak{p}$ since the constant terms of $(x)+\mathfrak{p}A[[x]]$ are exactly the elements of $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$. This concludes the proof.

(**Sidenote:** Does the same proof show that every maximal ideal of $A$ is the contraction of a maximal ideal in $A[[x]]$?)

Comment: For the maximal part if $m \in \operatorname{Max} (A)$, choose $\tilde m\in \operatorname{Spec}A[[x]]$ contracting to $m$ and then take a maximal ideal containing $\tilde m$ in $A[[x]]$.

Comment: Does the same proof not work, or is this another way to show the analogous result for maximal ideals?

Comment: The same proof works in the sense your proof shows a maximal ideal in $A$ is the contraction of a prime ideal in $A[[x]]$.